# Performance.mark() vs Performance.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

Can someone help me understand the difference between Performance.mark() vs Performance.now()? When would it be preferable to use one over the other?

Comment: They do (completely) different things? `mark(name)` sets a mark with the given name and returns a PerformanceMark, `now()` returns a monotonically increasing timestamp.